# ImageMagick `compare` precision

Tags: imagemagick, image-comparison

Probably a fairly simple question, but I can't seem to find an answer to it anywhere: When using ImageMagick's `compare` to figure out how different two images are, what degree of precision does the normalized cross correlation metric have?  In other words, how many decimal points and/or significant figures can I expect from the command `compare -metric NCC "$image1" "$image2" null: 2>&1`?  My few trials have seemed to get me 6 decimal places, but I'd like some confirmation that this simply isn't a coincidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Imagemagick, `compare` returns only 6 digits. But that is just a formatting. The precision is computed at least to full floating point precision if not double precision.

There is a -precision option, but it does not work with `compare`, thought it could be made so.

However, there is a newer `convert ... -compare` option that will allow you to get more precision. This has been available since 6.8.6-9. See https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#compare

```
convert -precision 10 lena.png lena.jpg -metric NCC -compare -format "%[distortion]\n" info:
0.9968860232
```